# Is it possible to double the size of everything below 800px viewport width?

Tags: fonts, media

I've got an issue where my text sizes start to get a bit small below about 800px. Something like a CSS property doing something like font-size: 200%, except I would prefer if it could just double the size of EVERYTHING, not just the text.

Is there a magic property I can throw on an HTML element?

Failing doubling everything, is there a CSS property to double all font sizes? I have several font sizes going on, so it would be nice to hit them with a percentage bonus.

My page has some nasty floats and clearfixes that I didnt create, so the logic is a bit haywire.

I recall some JS that would auto-resize everything, so something like that could work.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled across:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

That fixed it right up.